# Is there a way to explicitly generate multiple pytest results from a single pytest test case?

Tags: python, pytest

Requirement:

I have a test which talks to an external device and then retrieves the device output. The test needs to process this output, and then produce pytest results (pass/fail/skip) multiple times based on the return log within a single test.

For instance:

```
def test_run_device_tests():
    output_log = run_device_tests(cmd)
    for line in output_log:
         if "PASS" in line:
             # pass a pytest with a specific value as test name
         elif "FAIL" in line:
             # fail a pytest with a specific value as test name
             # and continue with the remaining parsing
```

I have considered using "pytest_generate_tests". But I do not see how I can utilize it as a "cmd" needs to be passed to get the output_log.

Comment: What is `cmd` and where does it come from? TBH from the code you provided, it's not quite clear what hinders you on splitting the test into multiple ones.

Comment: @hoefling Thanks for the comment. The reason it can't be split into multiple ones is because the output_log which has multiple pass/fail scenarios is generated from a SINGLE function call.

Comment: You can put that single function call in a fixture and analyze the same output log in different tests.

Comment: Correct. Is there a way to dynamically do this as I want to determine the tests at runtime from the log lines.

Comment: Sure, put the `run_device_tests` call in the hook, parse the log, parametrize tests.